GNU rush enable remote user to execute script
I'm trying to setup a user tomcat with shell /bin/rush.
rule runscript
  command ^script (.*)
  set [0] /bin/bash
  set [1] /usr/share/tomcat10/script.sh
  chdir ~

It works locally:
sudo -u tomcat script .
[normal output]

However when run through SSH and looking at the logs I have the following error message :
rush[144628]: /etc/rush.rc:31: runscript: cannot execute [1] /usr/share/tomcat10/script.sh: No such file or directory

File exists, belong to tomcat and is executable, I'm very confuse I feel like /etc/rush.rc do not support executable with . in it.
Do you have an idea on how I can allow a user to run script through SSH with rush as a shell ?
Binary executable seems to work as scp and rsync works without any trouble.

I was using the wrong syntax in my file:
set [0]

And I should have instead used:
    set[0]

I removed the space before the [ and that actually fixed my problem and everything works as expected.

You said, “It works locally”.   Can you explain that, if it was wrong all along?   Did you (contrary to what you show in the question) have it right (without the space) on your local system and simultaneously have it wrong on the remote system?
